# AWN displaying window icons even when Display Launchers Only selected

Tags: applet, dockbarx, awn

I'm using AWN with the DockbarX applet.I have Display Launchers Only checked in the awn dock properties, but I'm still getting window icons displaying for certain apps when they're open. Any ideas?

Here's a screenshot, note the Firefox icon at the top of the bar (shaded icon) which is part of the DockbarX applet,then note it displaying again at the bottom of the bar (indicating an open window.) You can see from the Launchers list in the dock properties that it isn't in fact a launcher. (The Yahoo and Gmail launchers are standalone Prism apps, they don't use the FF Prism extension. And if I mouse over the bottom FF icon, it does display the title of the open Firefox window, not anything using Prism.)

Any ideas? 
[image]

Comment: are using Avant from the ppa?

Comment: I was, but when I upgraded to Maverick it caused all kinds of problems so I removed it and installed the version from the software center. That said, when I look in the software center, under Provided by Ubuntu I have Avant Window Navigator, but there's still a PPA for Awn Testing Team listed, and the dockmanager-daemon package from that PPA is still installed. No idea what that means or if it has anything to do with the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: I know my comment is months after you posted this question, and there is a slim chance you are still even experiencing it. But have you tried a complete reinstall of AWN?

Comment: What applets are you using?

Comment: @tgm4883 - I'm actually not even using AWN anymore, so this isn't an issue. It may have been corrected in newer releases, if there have been any.